# Disappearing trails

Tags: discussion

I've had a recent run-in with a moderator (Dave Tweed), and it appears that after I offered to settle our differences, mano-a-mano, in an arena better suited for that than StackExchange, the entire thread disappeared.

Is that ability to alter history afforded to moderators, here, and if so, why?

Comment: I would if I could, but it's like the entire thread vanished without a trace.  it was about coilguns and the best time to turn off the magnet, if that helps.

Comment: Prompted by this question, I wrote a answer to the coil gun question (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/271135/4512).  If you have something *technical* to add, you still can.  Remember that content in comments is really no content at all, and that they can and sometimes are cleaned up.  If you have something to contribute, it's best to do so by writing your own answer.

Answer (score 9):

I deleted the comments by both of us from [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/271135/11683) after you correctly pointed out that they were not relevant to the topic at hand.

I really don't understand what you hope to accomplish by abusing me in some other context. I am only concerned with your actions on *this* site.

Comment: My initial response to the coilgun question was met with abuse in that  you chose to call it "silly" instead of objectively correcting my "error".  In the end I responded to the figurative slap on the cheek by  challenging you to a duel on neutral ground.  Your response was to obliterate the entire record in order to save face and preserve your image with as little damage as possible.

Comment: I obliterated the record in order to clean up the site. No other reason, and there was nothing wrong with my "face" or my "image". Seriously, what do you really think that the end result of a "duel" of words on some other site would be?

Comment: Nonsense. You obliterated the record so that you wouldn't  have to respond to my claim of your being a bully. This site has resources which one  can only dream of, so the "cleanup"  which you  used to obliterate what  came previously was a privilege which you abused  in order to maintain your stance as a judge.

Comment: @EMF Deleted comments are preserved in the database, and are accessible to moderators and the employees of Stack Exchange. If you believe there is evidence of moderator abuse in there, you can bring it directly to the attention of SE employees by using "contact us" link in the footer of the page. They can see all those comments.

Comment: @DaveTweed: You said, "Seriously, what do you really think that the end result of a "duel" of words on some other site would be?" A resolution of the prolem which now hangs in the air

Answer (score 9):

I don't know what specifically happened since I never saw the comment chain.  This isn't a specific answer to your question, but addresses the broader issue that is really behind your "question" (really more of a rant and a complaint about a particular moderator).

The basic problem is that you too often go around deliberately getting in people's faces.  It's OK to disagree about technical things, but you tend to go out of your way to make it personal.  When someone calls you on it, you almost invariably claim they are disagreeing with you to hide their incompetence.  You have a significant history of doing this, which I think is why you got so many downvotes (7 at this point) to this question in just a day.

You go around being a bully, but then accuse anyone who says anything about it as bullying you.  Since this happens repeatedly, you really should stop and ask yourself why you think these people are going out of their way to pick on you.

Here are some examples of unnecessarily inflammatory wording:

> Is that ability to alter history afforded to moderators

Surely you know by know that moderators can delete comments.  Obviously that's what was done.  Presenting that as "altering history", implying sensorship and the like, is just being obnoxious, especially since you almost certainly know exactly what happened.  I'm pretty sure I remember other meta posts where you asked about deleted comments.  This pretending to not know and "ask" what happened is quite disingenuous.

> was met with abuse

This is common tactic by you, which is to present your opinions and things that are clearly in dispute as facts.  It's about as obnoxious as *"Have you stopped beating your wife yet?"*.  The obvious purpose is to inflame.  Since you're not fooling anyone with this, others usually react negatively to you.

> I responded to the figurative slap on the cheek

More of the same.

> in order to save face and preserve your image

This is another common response of yours.  Whenever someone disagrees with you, it's always because you're right and they're trying to cover up their error.  This tactic takes a factual argument and deliberately makes it personal.  That just doesn't belong here, and is probably the primary reason people are tired of your complaints and downvote them so overwhelmingly.

Note that while you apparently think you score some debating points this way, you actually lose the argument immediately.  It basically says *"I don't have any real points to stand on, so I'll switch to making the other guy look bad."*.  This is a bad idea, because people see right thru this to the fact that you don't actually have a response on the issues.  It's a lot more transparent than you seem to think.

---

These examples are only from your question and some of the comments here.  There are many more out there, but the themes are largely the same.

Comment: Quite a clever ploy since you've been given  essentially infinite bandwidth to present your case as an answer,  and yet  I'm limited, by the system,  to about  500 characters, to reply to your erroneos claims.

Comment: @EMFields: Posts are limited to (I think) about 32 KB. You have just as much space in your question at the top of the page as Olin has here.

Comment: I was talking about the space available for an answer to a question as opposed to the space available  for comments related to that answer.  For example, Olin (or anyone) might pose an abundance of nonsensical  points in an "answer", yet refuting a single point could easily use up the allocated space allocated to a comment.

Answer (score 7):

Moderators have the ability to delete posts, and edit posts. Personally, I usually delete comment chains when they degrade into "Fight me, brah" or are proving Godwin's law. Comments disappear to non moderator users when deleted, but everything else has a public log. So I could certainly make it look like you had better judgement by deleting some of your comments and the rest of the community (including you) wouldn't see anything after they were deleted.

That being said, everything is logged, and moderators can't edit the log.